# single word to describe a person, who puts everything on social media

Tags: single-word-requests, social-media

I m looking for a **single word to describe a person, who puts everything on social media**. Imagine a person who is updating his status every second. Whatever he sees, the first thing he does is take a photo and put it in Snapchat, Instagram, Whatsapp and facebook for people to watch. any word other than social media addict or maniac.

Comment: I suspect what you're trying to describe is more a ***caricature, stereotype*** (that you want to poke fun at), rather than a real type of person. For example, have you ever *actually* known anyone who habitually updates their online status to reflect the fact that they're taking a dump or having sex?

Comment: I'd want to call them something like "vainly public" (which is how I would feel if doing so myself) however I have freinds that post everything they do who I would actually call fairly humble and down to earth .  I don't think they are showing off... they might see it as being social and friendly and 'open' and "staying in touch" with their friends.

Comment: I wasn't trying to describe a caricature or cartoon and believe me there are people who can't breath without updating their status. Its not they are arrogant or showing off. They are more like trapped in the virtual world. Their feelings, conversations and everything is there on online for the public to watch.

Comment: Taking this to the logical extreme, the person would be posting selfies of themself posting on whateverapp, and becoming absolutely incapable of doing _anything_ productive in an endless loop of postings...

Comment: You could used freak, buff, junkie, addict, nutcase, hophead, binger, crackhead and use Social media as prefix such as "Social media freak"

Answer (score 3):

> **Exhibitionist** *noun* a person who behaves in an extravagant way in order to attract attention: I am something of an exhibitionist.

Exhibitionist is not, of course, limited to social media but I suspect you'll have difficulty finding a word that refers exclusively to social media because the virtual world hasn't existed that long.

Exhibitionist is often related to nudity but context should make your meaning clear.

Comment: exhibitionist is a more negative word, right? even i thought of this word, but the meaning the word points to, like exhibiting their private body parts to public seems incorrect to what i was looking for. can i get a better word.

Comment: It is a more negative word. Maybe my prejudice read the negativity into your question. Showing off one's private parts if dnt really that different than posting everything's to digital society; it's all indecent exposure. Still, I hope you find your word